# Best way to display GADBannerView in SpriteKit/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, admob

So, I've found two ways of displaying google ads in my SpriteKit game... Both ways work, but I'm concerned that one of them is a more efficient etc.

My game just has 1 `ViewController` and 1 `GameScene`. The difference from the two implementations are when and where they are created.

Both require:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
var googleBannerView: GADBannerView!
```

This was the way I implemented it first:

in: GameViewController.swift

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {    
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

    googleBannerView.rootViewController = self
    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

    googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - googleBannerView.frame.size.height, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)

    self.view.addSubview(googleBannerView!)


    if let skView = self.view as? SKView {  //cast root as SKView
        if skView.scene == nil {
            //create and present gameScene
        }
    }
 }
```

This is the second way:

in: GameScene.swift

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

    googleBannerView.rootViewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

    googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - googleBannerView.frame.size.height, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)

    self.view?.addSubview(googleBannerView!)

    addChild(worldNode) //make whole world a node, create game nodes, in worldNode
    switchToMainMenu()  //go to menu menu
}
```

I think the only real difference is how you set the `rootViewController`, and given my game only has the 1 ViewController, both work...

Which would be the better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely be doing this via the view controller.  This makes more sense from a design standpoint.  The GameScene's job is to worry about game content only.  The view controller's job is to manage and control views (Hence the name "View Controller.")

Comment: I made the right decision for a change then aha. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: you could also use a helper such as the one I put on github. Having all the ads code in the viewController is also quite messy.           https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-2-iAds-and-AdMob-Helper

Comment: are you combining iAD and admob?  you can do iAd right through admob